# I can't boot ubuntu 13.04 from a usb stick

Tags: boot, usb

I had been using Universal USB Installer in order to create a bootable Ubuntu 13.04 USB. However, when I actually tried to boot it through BIOS on Windows 7 it just did not do anything. Screen would just freeze black. 
I did it with every 13.04 version available, but no results followed.

Earlier, I had been using same method with 12.04 and that time it had worked. Can anybody suggest something? Maybe another software for creating a bootable USB or some different means?

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/52726) answer.

Comment: UNetbootian is a good choice to install OS on USB it is very easy to use

Comment: UNetbootin usually works great.
Try use another USB stick.
Download the ISO again.

Comment: Did you use the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version? And do you use a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: I tried both 32 and 64 versions. I have windows 7 64bit version. 
Same thing with Unetbootin. Tried various USB sticks. Same thing :(

Comment: Startup disk creator from the Live CD works best for me.

Comment: Maybe it's for my USB is formated to FAT32 file system?

Answer (score 0):

Try using updated version of universal Usb installer in which ubuntu 13.04 is listed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Seth This is a half-answer; [it should *not* be a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments), and probably should not even be removed. **Happy Bhayana**: Can you expand this answer to explain *how* to do that?

Comment: @EliahKagan As a half answer it should be a comment. Answers are for *answers* not *ideas* that might solve the problem.

Comment: @Seth That is entirely incorrect. Please read the linked meta post.

Comment: @EliahKagan I disagree that half-answers be considered answers at all. I downvoted that question. If someone can't post a full answer but has pointers, they go in the comments. NOT the answer section.

Comment: @Seth You seem to disagree at least in part with [that meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281), which represents a strong community consensus. Perhaps you agree in part but think its scope should be narrower. Of course at least some half-answers and partial answers should be deleted. But I recommend against advising anyone to post them as comments; to do so is to mislead people about what our community as a whole considers good practice. If you disagree with the consensus established in that meta question, I recommend discussing it on meta, possibly by posting a new meta question.